# Selecting rows based on duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, filtering

I basically have results grid and i have a drop down menu on my application which filters the 'Carrier' column. But when selecting a certain carrier I want all the rows returned that have the same dr_id as the Carrier which has been selected.

For example if you look at the picture attached it shows my results grid. If I filter by carrier 'ACE CALL LTD_UK' then I want rows 27, 28, 29 and 30 returned because the dr_id is the same.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a complete solution for you as I don't know exactly what you database schema is (and it is a large stored procedure!). However I do have some suggestions/comments which you might find helpful:

I assume that the stored procedure will currently be returning a single row when they filter is set to 'ACE CALL LTD_UK', if not then this might not be relevant!

What I would do in this case would be to take you `SELECT` statement and put the results into a `CTE`, temporary table or nested query. (I'm not sure what SQL DBMS your using, looks like MSSQL, but you also have a MySQL tag for you post).

Once I have those results I would then use a `LEFT JOIN` from the `dr_id` in the temp table back to the `drm` table on the same column. From here you will again need to join to other tables where the data is not distinct, for example the `Carrier` table, then select the columns that you require.

You could do all this in the existing `SELECT` statement, however you will have to start joining on tables multiple times or use nested queries, which would get very messy. However the main reason why I chose the solution I have posted is because I don't know the stored procedure well enough and therefore I chose the safest solution.

If you want an example of what I mean, I will try and provide one.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the SP returns more than one row when filtered by 'ACE CALL LTD_UK' so i dont think that will work...

Cheers

Comment: It should still work with multiple rows, just as long as the `dr_id`s are separate for each row, otherwise you will start getting duplicates. I just had a closer look at you screenshot and I can see this would be the case from the visible records.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I managed to do it with a simpler query. SELECT *
FROM FullResults
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID 
            FROM FullResults
            WHERE Type= @variable);

Comment: I would probably suggest you add an identity column and use that for the basis of the answer above. Once you have an identity column, you should be able to use this as a basis to inner join back to the same table to obtain relative results (join via dr_id) which will also filter any duplicates (as it will duplicate results when filtering by 'ACE CALL LTD_UK'). You could also use the identity in your drop down to assist with a better execution plan.